# To achieve concurrency in kafka listener, how are defining consumer groups using groupId & concurrency in @KafkaListener different?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

If we have > 1 partition for a topic, then we can have a consumer group, now the different consumers in this group will split the partitions they want to read from.

We have one more option where in we don't use consumer group, but define concurrency = 2 (for eg), now 2 instances of the consumer runs each reading from a different partition.

How are these 2 different ? or are they same under the hood ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can treat that concurrency option of `@KafkaListener` as number of consumer group members. From Kafka perspective it is indeed the same if we would just start another instance of our application.

We don't use a consumer group only if we do a manual assignment. Otherwise an auto-generated `id` for `@KafkaListener` is used as a `groupId`. Or an exception is thrown:

```
        Assert.state(hasGroupIdConsumerConfig || StringUtils.hasText(this.containerProperties.getGroupId()),
                "No group.id found in consumer config, container properties, or @KafkaListener annotation; "
                        + "a group.id is required when group management is used.");
```

Comment: so we can also use concurrency option in place of a consumer group, and the different concurrent consumers also divide the partitions among themselves like consumer group does ?
If yes, then what is the advantage / disadvantage of using one over the other ?

Comment: That's not what I said. What I mean that concurrency on a listener container just creates those extra `KafkaConsumer` instances, as it would be if you start several instances of the same application. All these consumers belongs to the same group and Kafka rebalance topics to subscribe respectively. It is still a consumer group. The concurrency does not replace, but rather provide a convenience to have several `KafkaConsumer` instances in the same application. It is not correct to say "replace consumer group" because it is a native feature of Apache Kafka and it cannot be removed.